# trouble deleting a dynamic linked list?

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

```
  struct Package_Node
    {
        int bar_code;
        float package_weight;
        Package_Node *next_packaged;
    };

    struct Key_Node
    {
        int key;
        Package_Node *next_package;
    };        

   for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                if(keyMain[i].next_package==NULL)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if(keyMain[i].next_package!=NULL)
                {
                    nPointer3=keyMain[i].next_package;
                    nPointer4=keyMain[i].next_package;
                    while(nPointer3)
                    {
                        nPointer4=nPointer4->next_packaged;
                        delete[] nPointer3;
                        nPointer3=nPointer4;
                    }
                }
            }
```

`keyMain` an array which is described by the given struct `key_node`.

Key main itself is a dynamic array but for the sake of code I have shown it to be a static array.

Lets say the array is 3 indexes long, `0,1,2` and each index contains a separate linked-list. Now I am trying to delete each of the linked list, but seems like some are being deleted and others are not.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you show the lines where the memory pointed to by nPointer3 is allocated?

Comment: Why are you using `delete []` for the `Package_Node` elements?  If they are arrays, what about the rest of the array?

Comment: @ChrisDodd `Package_Node` is not array. Its a linked list. `Key_node` however is an array.

Comment: @Digikata I am not sure what your question is, but if I understand it correctly, `nPointer3` is a pointer that points to a `package_node`. I used `package_node *nPointer3` and then created allocated dynamic memory using `nPackage = new Package_node`

Comment: If you allocate one node at a time with _new Package_Node_, you will get undefined behavior releasing the memory with the array delete operator _delete []_. The memory allocated from the singular _new_ operator should be released with singular _delete_. Similarly, the array delete should only be paired with the array new operator _new Type[n]_.

Comment: @Digikata yes, `Package_Node` was added to the list one one node at a time. The loop just ran, say 10 times to add 10 different links to the list, like a linked list. Seems like some of the nodes are being deleted while some stay. I am completely unsure how to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing wrong here?  For one, you are manually managing memory.

```
#include <memory>

struct Package_Node
{
  int bar_code;
  float package_weight;
  std::unique_ptr<Package_Node> next_packaged;
};

struct Key_Node
{
  int key;
  std::unique_ptr<Package_Node> next_package;
};
```

To store a pointer in a `unique_ptr`, use `reset(new Package_Node())`.  Instead of `delete`, call `reset()`.  Anything pointed to by a `unique_ptr` gets automatically deleted when the `unique_ptr` is deleted.

This is C++11 -- in C++03, you may have `std::tr1::unique_ptr`, or `boost::unique_ptr`, but without move semantics `unique_ptr` is more dangerous to use.

---

Now, if you do the above, your code becomes much shorter, and deallocating an entire linked list is just a matter of `.reset()` the smart pointer to the first node: everything else is erased automatically!

However, you might not be willing to do this.  So I'll attack some other problems in your code.

Your variable names do not reflect the usage of the values.  `nPointer4` is a horrible variable name.  Try `PointerToDelete` that documents what its purpose is.  In addition, you should declare the pointer at the point of initialization, and clear it the moment it is invalid, rather than have it hang around before or after its use.  (You get no bonus points for reusing variables).

Looking at this loop:

```
            nPointer3=keyMain[i].next_package;
            nPointer4=keyMain[i].next_package;
            while(nPointer3)
            {
                nPointer4=nPointer4->next_packaged;
                delete[] nPointer3;
                nPointer3=nPointer4;
            }
```

note that `nPointer3` and `nPointer4` should hold the same data at the start of the `while`, so why do they both exist?  You could halve your state by rewriting like this:

```
            Package_Node* ptrToDelete=keyMain[i].next_package;
            while(ptrToDelete)
            {
                Package_Node* nextPtr = ptrToDelete->next_packaged;
                delete ptrToDelete;
                ptrToDelete = nextPtr;
            }
```

Notice how `ptrToDelete` exists only at the moment it is initialized.

Notice how `nextPtr` exists as short a time as it can, and then goes out of scope.  It also exists only once it is initialized.

Next, always always post compiling code that actually demonstrates your problem.  Your code above does not compile for reasons completely unrelated to your problem, and reading your mind is not something you should be asking people to do.

You don't know what is wrong, so how do you know what is or is not important?  Easy: let your compiler figure it out.  Produce a simple example that demonstrates the problem you have, compile it, test that the problem still occurs, then post *that*.

Instead of having a problem, removing parts to make it shorter, posting non-compiling code that may or may not still have the problem, and hoping that other people can read your mind.

Your use of `struct Package_Node*` is completely unnecessary -- `Package_Node*` is shorter and (barring some extreme corner cases) does exactly the same thing.

Even if you don't use smart pointers, a `struct` that owns a pointer should destroy it in its destructor, and if it doesn't own the pointer something else should.  [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) is your friend.  Don't forget to follow the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) when you make a `struct` that owns a pointer.

Comment: I am not managing memory manually here. I just used the manual thing for the sake of code.

Comment: the entire program is around 700 lines long and I have done the entire program using the given `structs`. Is there any other way to solve this? Also I really have to stick with the given `structs` as this is a school project.

Comment: @QaziHossain That makes no sense.  "I am not managing memory manually here" and "I just used the manual thing" -- you either are managing memory manually, or you are not.

Comment: the code is around 700 lines long, I would have posted the entire code, but I dont think anybody will read a code that long. The code is working fully except the part where it is asking the compiler to delete all the members of the linked list. It is deleting some of the members but rest are still there.

Comment: @QaziHossain Don't post the entire code.  Post a self contained, complete, short example that ACTUALLY COMPILES and demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you check whether things have been deleted; once you've deallocated memory, that memory can be reused and you're not allowed to access it any more - although nobody will stop you unless you cause a runtime error - but that memory's content isn't modified by the deallocation.
You can't tell by inspection that a particular object has been deallocated.

I believe your problem is that you forgot to set `keyMain[i].next_package` to `NULL` when you're done.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    if (keyMain[i].next_package != NULL)
    {
        Package_Node* current = keyMain[i].next_package;
        Package_Node* next = 0;
        while (current)
        {
            next = current->next_package;
            // No "[]" since you're apparently not allocating with "[]"
            delete current;
            current = next;
        }
        keyMain[i].next_package = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're deleting `keyMain[i].next_package` twice -- once with `delete[]` in the first iteration of the loop and a second time with `delete` after the loop

Comment: so you are saying everything is right except that I need to set each pointer within the `key_node` to null?

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: @molbdnilo if I just point `keyMain[i].next_package` to `NULL`, the printout wont show the linked list anymore, but how do I know that the memory allocated with the linked list has been freed? Is my code doing the right thing?

Comment: @QaziHossain Yes, as far as I can see from your code, but I would suggest you look over your variable scoping and naming principles, too. Variables with nondescriptive names or unnecessarily large scopes make code much harder to understand, and that tends to lead to bugs.

Comment: @QaziHossain As I said, you can't inspect memory to see if it's been deallocated. All you can do is work through the loop and convince yourself that every element is being deleted. In other words, use logic. When you didn't set it to `NULL`, you were just printing things that had been left behind when those objects were freed - there wasn't actually a list there any more. Sometimes that memory had been reused and set to 0, entirely by chance.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, when I try to print the list after deleting the linked list, some elements are zero while others have garbage and 1 or 2 nodes are not deleted at all. –

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned in comments that nPointer3 memory is allocated via "new Package_Node", the line "delete[] nPointer3;" should read:

```
delete nPointer3;
nPointer3 = NULL;  // recommended (mentioned in another answer)
```

The behavior you describe could result from the undefined behavior in trying to release nPointer3 memory that was allocated via singular new.  Only memory allocated via the array new operator "new[]" (e.g. new Package_Node[16]) should be released with "delete []".